# When should I use SELECT CAST or SELECT SAFE_CAST instead of just CAST in SQL?

Tags: sql, syntax, casting, .when

Would there be much difference if I used `CAST` instead of `SELECT CAST` or `SELECT SAFE_CAST`? Thank you in advance.

I'm having trouble understanding when to use these. I understood `CAST` but then I learned `SELECT CAST` and `SELECT SAFE_CAST` wondering if there are kinds of scenarios when it's only applicable to use `SELECT SAFE_CAST` or `SELECT CAST`.

Comment: It depends on your column value. If you not sure all data can converting you must use safe_cast else you can use cast. Safe_cast is alternative of try_cast (sql server) and cast is the same in sql server also.

Answer (score 0):

`SAFE_CAST` is best used if there is a likelihood of a casting error for example if converting strings to dates the string `31-Feb-2023` cannot be converted to a date. In this case `SAFE_CAST` returns a NULL and allows the query to proceed. In the final output the user may then inspect all cases where the conversion resulted in NULL and perhaps correct the input to a proper date. Using `CAST` alone would just produce an error message and you would probably not know which row caused the error. e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE date_table (
    valid_date date,
    string_date varchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO date_table (valid_date, string_date)
VALUES
    ('2023-01-01', '31-Feb-2023'),
    ('2023-02-15', '14-Mar-2023'),
    ('2023-03-10', 'ABC-2023-04-01');


-- Example using SAFE_CAST function
SELECT valid_date, SAFE_CAST(string_date AS date) AS converted_date
FROM date_table;
```

However, this will crash because some strings just cannot be converted into a date:

```
-- Example using CAST function TRY THIS
SELECT valid_date, CAST(string_date AS date) AS converted_date
FROM date_table;
```

In the opposite direction, if we have a column of a specific data type and wish to convert that to strings then you don't require safe_cast:

```
SELECT CAST(valid_date AS text) AS string_date
FROM date_table;
```

although it is more likely you would format e.g.

```
SELECT valid_date, TO_CHAR(valid_date, 'FMMonth DD, YYYY') AS formatted_date
FROM date_table;
```

Perhaps try the above SQL at https://dbfiddle.uk